# É possível eu criar uma classe em tempo de execução no Python?

Tags: python, orientação-a-objetos, reflexão

Queria criar uma classe em tempo de execução para fazer umas atualizações em bancos de dados, por exemplo, mas sem ficar dependente do SGBD e sim utilizar python e queria saber se é possível a criação dessas classes em tempo de execução.

Comment: Tem algumas técnicas, mas criar a classe é o menor dos problemas, para fazer isso precisa arquiteturar a aplicação muito bem. É difícil, mas possível, se valer só disto para deixar o software flexível. Eu conheço uma grande empresa que fez errado e isto custa milhões a ele e seus clientes. Eu gosto da ideia, mas salvo em situações bem genéricas dá muito trabalho fazer certo e precisa ter motivo pra compensar.

Comment: Tem como explicar melhor o que deseja fazer? Tem certeza que o que precisa é criar uma classe e não apenas uma instancia?

Comment: Para acesso a SGBD eu optaria pelo [SQLAlchemy](https://www.sqlalchemy.org/). Mas de qq forma coloquei minha resposta.

Answer (score 5):

Na linguagem Python, é trivial criar classes em tempo de execução - 
e com algum trabalho e cuidado, você pode até criar classes instrumentadas com funcionalidades ORM (Mapeamento Objeto Relacional)  que funcionem bem.

O seu sistema fazer bom uso delas, claro, vai depender de outros componentes - não só a parte que "fala" com o banco de dados ter como usar dados dessas classes construídas dinamicamente para poderem fazer algo útil. (Quais campos serão exibidos na UI? Em que ordem? Que usuários podem modificar quais campos?? )

É possível sim construir um exemplo que introspecte a base de dados e a partir daí seja completamente dinâmico. (E na verdade vai fazer pouca diferença se os elementos de uma dada tabela estão representados por uma classe de Python internamente, ou em uma estrutura "burra" como dicionário) - mas *via de regra* é melor você definir bem alguns modelos para o seu sistema e ter esses modelos - pelo menos alguns campos - colocados como código no seu sistema.

Tudo isso dito, para se criar uma nova classe em Python, basta chamar o construtor `type`, passando os parâmetros "nome", "bases" e "namespace" - esse último é um dicionário com as declarações equivalentes a que colocamos no corpo de uma classe escrita com a palavra chave  `class`:

```
def init(self):
   print("Inicializando ", self)

MinhaClasse = type("MinhaClasse", (object,), {"__init__": init})

MinhaClasse()
```

Pronto - MinhaClase foi criada em tempo de execução com valores que poderiam estar em vaiáveis. Agora, dar alguma utilidade para isso é outra história.  (Por exemplo, você pode setar no namespace um parâmetro "atributos" - e fazer com que o código de `__init__` possa receber esses atributos como named parameters e atribui-los automaticamente à instância:

```
class Base:
    atributos = ""
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
         for atributo in atributos.split():
             setattr(self, atributo, kwargs.pop(atributo, None))

ClassePessoa = type("ClassePessoa", (Base,), {'atributos': 'nome idade'})

p1 = ClassePessoa(nome='Lucas', idade=23)
print(p1.nome)
```

Answer (score 5):

([TL;DR](https://anaconda.org/sidon/python_type_class/notebook))

É possível e, na verdade, relativamente fácil, embora trabalhoso. Vou reproduzir uma explicação/exemplo bem difundido na internet:

Em primeiro lugar, vamos nos concentrar na relação entre `type` e `class`. Quando definimos classes podemos nos perguntar "o que acontece nos bastidores". Podemos ver que se aplicarmos type em um objeto, o retorno é a classe da qual aquele objeto foi instanciado.

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = "Hello"
print(type(a), type(b))
<class 'list'> <class 'str'>
```

Se aplicarmos type no nome da classe, obteremos o "tipo" class:

```
print(type(list), type(str))
<class 'type'> <class 'type'>
```

Isto é similar a aplicarmos type em type(a) e type(b)

```
a = [4, 5, 9]
b = "Hello"
print(type(a), type(b))
print(type(type(a)), type(type(b)))
<class 'list'> <class 'str'>
<class 'type'> <class 'type'>
```

Uma classe definida pelo usuário (ou objeto classe) é uma instância da classe "type". Como se pode ver, as classes são criadas a partir de type. Em python3 não há diferença entre "classes" e "types". Esses termos podem, em muitos casos, serem usados como sinomimos.

O fato de classes serem instancias de um classe "type" permite ou suporta o uso de metaclasses. Podemos criar classes, que herdam diretamente da classe "type", dessa forma, uma metaclasse é uma sublcasse da classe "type".

Type pode ser chamada com três argumentos

`type(classname, superclasses, attributes_dict)`

Quando type é chamado com 3 argumentos, retorna um novo tipo de objeto. Isso proporcina um forma de delcarar uma classe dinamicamente.

- "classname" é a string que define o nome da classe e se tornará o atributo **name**;
- "superclass" é uma lista ou tupla com as superclasses da nossa classe. Este parametro se tornará o atributo **base**
- O parametro attributes_dict é um dicionário que funcionará como o namespace de nossa classe. Contem as definições do corpo da classe e se tornará o atributo **dict**

Vejamos uma simples definição

```
class A:
    pass
x = A()
print(type(x))
<class '__main__.A'>
```

Podemos usar "type" para definirmos a classe A:

```
A = type("A", (), {})
x = A()
print(type(x))
<class '__main__.A'>
```

Quando chamamos "type", o metodo **call** de type é chamado. O método **call** executa outros dois métodos: **new** e **init**:

```
type.__new__(typeclass, classname, superclasses, attributedict)
type.__init__(cls, classname, superclasses, attributedict)
```

O método **new** cria e retorna o novo objeto do tipo class e, em seguida, o método **init** inicializa a nova classe criada.

Veja duas classes identicas (Robot), definidas de duas maneiras completamente diferentes em termos sintáticos:

```
class Robot1:
    counter = 0
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def sayHello(self):
        return "Hi, I am " + self.name


def Rob_init(self, name):
    self.name = name

Robot2 = type("Robot2", 
              (), 
              {"counter":0, 
               "__init__": Rob_init,
               "sayHello": lambda self: "Hi, I am " + self.name})
```

Agora vamos instanciar as duas classes e apresentar seus atributos:

```
r1 = Robot('Robocop')
print(r1.name)
print(r1.sayHello())
print(r1.__dict__)
print(r1.__dict__)  
Robocop
Hi, I am Robocop
{'name': 'Robocop'}
{'name': 'Robocop'}

r2 = Robot2('Robocop')
print(r2.name)
print(r2.sayHello())
print(r2.__dict__)
print(r2.__dict__) 
Robocop
Hi, I am Robocop
{'name': 'Robocop'}
{'name': 'Robocop'}
```

Com essa explanação é possível perceber que, em python, é relativamente fácil (comparado com outras linguagens/plataformas) definir classes de forma dinamica.

[Veja essa explanação e o código rodando em um jupyter notebook.](https://anaconda.org/sidon/python_type_class/notebook)